# how get Virtual memory for windows phone 'mango'

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my application I want to find out the Virtual memory for the device(windows phone 'mango')

and how much is used and how much is free

(for now I am only able to get the phone memory however it is not showing free,used or any other info)

Please help

Sneha

Answer (score 0):

System memory is nothing of your concern.

Use Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage to find your current usage and 
Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("ApplicationWorkingSetLimit") to find the limit. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff707583%28v=vs.92%29.aspx
If current exceeds the limit, your app will be killed. That's all you have to worry about.

Or maybe you were thinking not about memory but disk space? You can store files in IsolatedStorage only, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

like System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.AvailableFreeSpace